# Drawing outside a window in Java?

Tags: java, paint

Is it possible to simply `paint()` (or use some other function) to the screen in Java?  As in draw over everything else on some coordinates of the screen itself, not inside some window.

If not, is it possible to make an invisible window that takes up the entire screen and use its glass pane to do it?  Would complications arise from doing this?  (Such as not being able to click on other applications)

Are there any other ways?

Thanks.

**Edit:**  I'm not trying to do full screen with this, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you can create an transparent undecorated maximized JFrame. This will allow you to "paint" over the desktop. Problems are obvious: if an application stays behind this window, it will not receive any mouse events.

Months ago, I made an evil cheat to draw directly on Windows Explorer's Desktop: mixing some .NET coding with JNI and Sun's internal classes - that's surreal, but works.

Comment: Would the first suggestion work in an applet?  In ALL OSes?  That's what I need this for.

Comment: In theory, yes, but you run an applet with "all privileges" (that's evil). Oh, and undecorated frames may not work on applets.

Comment: Would these problems be solved if I got the applet signed by VersiSign or something?

Comment: I guess not. The undecorated frame because Java must identify "Java Applet Windows" with that funny label on top-right. And "all privileges" will require user intervention on JDK's configuration. Applets are not suitable for that. Webstart can do a better job.

Comment: Okay, Thanks.  I'm going to do it in Webstart.

Comment: Would you mind sharing this code if you still have it?

Comment: That was in 2011. I can't even remember if I did this at home or at work. :(

Answer (score 2):

When you `paint()` in Java, you're painting only within the confines of the size and location of what is being `paint()`ed.

If you're looking to do full screen stuff, there are tutorials for that:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html